# How to store multiple Shifts in Relational Timetable Database

Tags: database, relational-database

I have the following tables:

```
Employees
id,surname,name,dob,pos

workinghours
id, start time, end time,

records
employee.id, workinghours.id, start time, end time
```

I'm trying to add the workinghours for the whole week to the employees table as in
Mon shift1, tue shift2, wed shift, to the employees table.

I've read about adding weekdays, assigning 1-7 to each and using it in the records.

Is there any more efficient ways to do this?

- Is JSON better for this ?
- How should I handle this?

Comment: Assuming they work a guarnateed fixed weekly rotation, that never changes, having a weekday_id column is fine.  Every workforce management system I've ever worked with, however, recognises that holidays, bank holiday, shift swaps, pattern changes, etc, mess that up.  As such, a more normal approach would be to have an actual date or datetime column, and store every shift individually, rather than trying to save a tiny bit of space with a rotation.  By all means use templates in order to populate it, but record actual shifts for actual dates.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer, what do you mean by 'have an actual date or datetime column, and store every shift individually'? to the shifts?

Comment: Cannot edit the post cause someone suggested an edit, revoked it or somehow it doesnt show. i guess you mean datetime for historical shifts, i dont really get how it does the Job here. i'd add datetime to the historical shifts, but if i add it to the actual set shifts i need the day only